# GCP Compute Engine VM startup-script and SSH Breaks after `apt-get update`

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, debian, google-compute-engine

To install git on  `e2-medium (2 vCPUs, 4 GB memory) Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)` instances, we run the following script defined in the  `startup-script-url` as per the instructions seen here: [GCP Startup Scripts on Linux.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts/linux)

After running `sudo apt-get update` or `sudo apt update` the behavior for the VMS change:

1. Startup scripts don't seem to execute after stopping, and resuming VMs
2. Cannot SSH via web console via GCP GUI.

Any thoughts on why this is happening and how to fix this? We've temporarily worked around by installing git from source.

---

**startupscript.sh**

Defined as `--metadata startup-script-url=gs://my-project/startupscript.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! command -v git &> /dev/null
then
    echo "============================================"
    echo "GIT WAS NOT FOUND. PLEASE INSTALL"
    sudo apt -y update 
    sudo apt install -y git-all
    echo "============================================"
fi

echo "CONTINUE TO DO MORE HERE"
```

---

**1. Initital Successful Run**

CHECK STARTUP SCRIPT LOGS

- SSH into VM
- Run `sudo journalctl -xefu google-startup-scripts -f`

The script has run successfully as per logs below:

```
Oct 29 14:48:48 instance-1 google_metadata_script_runner[521]: startup-script-url: Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
Oct 29 14:49:09 instance-1 google_metadata_script_runner[521]: startup-script-url: Processing triggers for install-info (6.5.0.dfsg.1-4+b1) ...
Oct 29 14:49:09 instance-1 google_metadata_script_runner[521]: startup-script-url: Processing triggers for mime-support (3.62) ...
Oct 29 14:49:09 instance-1 google_metadata_script_runner[521]: startup-script-url: Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.58.3-2+deb10u3) ...
Oct 29 14:49:09 instance-1 google_metadata_script_runner[521]: startup-script-url: Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.28-10) ...
Oct 29 14:49:09 instance-1 google_metadata_script_runner[521]: startup-script-url: Setting up glib-networking:amd64 (2.58.0-2+deb10u2) ...
Oct 29 14:49:09 instance-1 google_metadata_script_runner[521]: startup-script-url: Setting up libsoup2.4-1:amd64 (2.64.2-2) ...
Oct 29 14:49:09 instance-1 google_metadata_script_runner[521]: startup-script-url: Setting up libsoup-gnome2.4-1:amd64 (2.64.2-2) ...
Oct 29 14:49:09 instance-1 google_metadata_script_runner[521]: startup-script-url: Setting up librest-0.7-0:amd64 (0.8.1-1) ...
Oct 29 14:49:09 instance-1 google_metadata_script_runner[521]: startup-script-url: Setting up libgtk-3-0:amd64 (3.24.5-1) ...
Oct 29 14:49:09 instance-1 google_metadata_script_runner[521]: startup-script-url: Setting up emacs-gtk (1:26.1+1-3.2+deb10u2) ...
Oct 29 14:49:09 instance-1 google_metadata_script_runner[521]: startup-script-url: update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/emacs-gtk to provide /usr/bin/emacs (emacs) in auto mode
Oct 29 14:49:09 instance-1 google_metadata_script_runner[521]: startup-script-url: Install emacsen-common for emacs
Oct 29 14:49:09 instance-1 google_metadata_script_runner[521]: startup-script-url: emacsen-common: Handling install of emacsen flavor emacs
Oct 29 14:49:09 instance-1 google_metadata_script_runner[521]: startup-script-url: Install git for emacs
Oct 29 14:49:09 instance-1 google_metadata_script_runner[521]: startup-script-url: Setting up git-el (1:2.20.1-2+deb10u3) ...
Oct 29 14:49:10 instance-1 google_metadata_script_runner[521]: startup-script-url: Install git for emacs
Oct 29 14:49:10 instance-1 google_metadata_script_runner[521]: startup-script-url: Install git for emacs
Oct 29 14:49:10 instance-1 google_metadata_script_runner[521]: startup-script-url: Setting up emacs (1:26.1+1-3.2+deb10u2) ...
Oct 29 14:49:10 instance-1 google_metadata_script_runner[521]: startup-script-url: Setting up git-all (1:2.20.1-2+deb10u3) ...
Oct 29 14:49:10 instance-1 google_metadata_script_runner[521]: startup-script-url: Processing triggers for libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64 (2.38.1+dfsg-1) ...
Oct 29 14:49:10 instance-1 google_metadata_script_runner[521]: startup-script-url: Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.28-10) ...
Oct 29 14:49:10 instance-1 sudo[1212]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Oct 29 14:49:10 instance-1 google_metadata_script_runner[521]: startup-script-url: ============================================
Oct 29 14:49:10 instance-1 google_metadata_script_runner[521]: startup-script-url: CONTINUE TO DO MORE HERE
Oct 29 14:49:10 instance-1 google_metadata_script_runner[521]: startup-script-url exit status 0
```

ALSO VALIDATE IN GOOGLE CLOUD LOGGING

Cloud Logging only displays up until the `Processing triggers for man-db` log, which is a bit weird, but it appears that all would have installed.

[image: Logging only displays up until the Processing triggers for man-db log, but we assume everything to have installed correctly.]

---

**2. Power Off**

`sudo poweroff`

---

**3. Start VM from GUI**

Startup script execution, and web ssh are broken.

CHECK STARTUP SCRIPT LOGS

- SSH into VM
- Run `sudo journalctl -xefu google-startup-scripts -f`

```
No journal files were found.
```

ALSO VALIDATE IN GOOGLE CLOUD LOGGING

No logs can be seen other than the startup. Also no indication that startup-script-url metadata found (which typically occurs)

[image]

WEB SSH NO LONGER WORKS

[image]

Boot Logs

`journalctl -b`

```
No journal files were found
-- No entries --
```

`sudo /var/log/dmesg`

```
command not found
```

`/var/log/boot.log`

```
-bash: /var/log/boot.log: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You are leaving out a lot of details. Startup scripts always run at startup. What makes you think they do not run? Connect via the serial console, review the boot logs. You will find your problem there. Edit your question and include details that indicate what problems exist and the log messages. Do not post the entire log, just the important parts. 2) I do not recommend **git-all**. Install just the **git** package.

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley thanks for the feedback. I've added the logs from `sudo journalctl -xefu google-startup-scripts -f`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here when we are installing **git-all** it  replaces the systemd init system with the older SysV init system, breaking `cloud-init` and pretty much all the booting process.This is the reason why you're unable to SSH into your instance.

There are 2 possible fixes for this issue :

1. As @John Hanley told try using git instead of git-all.
2. If git-all is mandatory then try using **apt install
   --no-install-recommends -y git-all** this will make sure that recommends are not getting installed.

Answer (score 1):

GCP startup scripts run at container creation, not at Linux startup (those "subsequent startups" are a delusion). And the script by itself is non-sensical; just do `apt install -y git`. There simply is no point to check if the package exists, when `aptitude` performs just the same check (one can see in to logs when trying unnecessary packages). Be aware that everything this script does will run as user `root` and be owned by user `root`, which might require the one or other `chmod` or `chown`. "VMs no longer work as expected" is nothing I could reproduce; that's not an error description.

Comment: Updated question. Hopefully it adds a bit of clarity